# moving\jumping page after clicking a link

Tags: html, css

I try to make a page after tutorial and I have a question why my page jums or moves during refreshing when I clik for example on the bar? On  the tutorial the page isn't jump and my jumps??? Click on the blue bar and the page jums or moves what is wrong with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Blog na temat ciekawych publikacji z dziedziny filozofii. Omówienie wybranych tekstów najsłynniejszych autorów!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="filozofia, książki, blog, przemyślenia">
    <meta name="author" content="Wojciech Bukowski">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE-edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Philosophia Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>Philosophia Blog</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div id="topbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Strona Główna</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Pierwszy raz tutaj?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Dlaczego filozofia?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">O autorze</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your code, if you don't want this to happen remove the href in your anchor tag. However, by the looks of your code, you're trying to make a navbar. So for now, don't worry about what's happening and keep going with the tutorial!